# On assuming context of the reader in PSE?

Tags: discussion

So I think I can't guess the context of the reader but as an exercise can someone tell me how to improve my question writing for example here:

[What is the size of the dirac delta function in FLRW metric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/786623/what-is-the-size-of-the-dirac-delta-function-in-flrw-metric)

Edit

Me and the moderator managed to reach some sort of understanding on the validity of the question:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64656807#64656807

(Would recommend a complete reading here is the gist of it)

> I don't think anyone thinks FLRW is a particularly accurate model of
> the universe at all, it's just a model for the very large-scale
> structure on top of which you can then layer the local perturbations
> that correspond to galaxy clusters and whatnot

-Acuriousmind

Comment: "Me and the moderator managed to reach some sort of understanding..." Why don't you summarize that understanding here? I read through the chat and I don't see that you came to any kind of understanding...

Comment: The fact that it took dozens upon dozens of messages between you two to even elucidate a single component of the question is highly indicative that you cannot express your ideas in any meaningful way without a lot of discussion with someone else. More pointedly, you appear to be using words and phrases that most people would understand in one way but you mean it in some entirely different meaning w/o explaining the intended meaning.

Comment: @KyleKanos feel free to post an answer

Comment: Also feel free to post examples of "words and phrases that most people would understand in one way but you mean it in some entirely different meaning w/o explaining the intended meaning."

Comment: @hft what happened in the conversation according to you?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous From [this remark from ACuriousMind](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64656924#64656924) and down, which outlines the difference between your use of the "$\delta$-function in QM" and what everyone else reads it to mean.

Comment: I mean I don't think of all dirac deltas the same way (nor did I say so). I just think you need a different theory or initial condition (metric) to do so. And the dirac delta function is a limit of the theory

Comment: You didn't say anything about it. You assumed that your meaning of the phrase is read by everyone the same as you. But that's not the case. Physics has a precise language and you aren't using it or are using it incorrectly. If you want people to have the context, you need to be on the same page as everyone else (and I'm specifically saying that it is not us who needs to be on your page).

Comment: No offense, but I think your knowledge of physics is quite disorganized, and you would benefit a lot from sitting down and reading a standard textbook or two from front to back, working out the problems. Without such a foundation, you can't really get a clear picture of physics, even if you ask thousands of questions here.

Comment: I think I would really benefit if I had circumstances to access academia again :/

Comment: *...if I had circumstances to access academia again* Fun fact: both [Autodidacticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodidacticism) and [MOOCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course) exist.

Comment: I mean I do go through a lot of resources just not in the same structured way as that of a university

Comment: You don’t need a university to have structure. Most of my learning was done outside of classes by reading textbooks front to back. I think the deeper problem is that you might be skimming a lot of things without taking the time to deeply understand the core material.

Comment: I don't think this question demonstrates a lack of understanding but rather a lack of contextual understanding of the audience is placed?

Comment: @knzhou I do however face lack of problems sheets (I don't have means to cross check the answers)

Comment: You don't need university problem sheets to have physics problems. Many problems are "self-checking" (i.e. it's easy to tell if you went wrong), plus books have lots of worked examples, and solutions online.

Answer (score 4):

Your question about the Dirac delta in the FLRW metric is like asking about Justin Bieber's greatest hits in Schwarzschild spacetime. Those things have nothing to do with each other, so there's not much to improve. That question didn't make any sense at all.

The FLRW metric is homogenous and isotropic, so there isn't any Dirac delta anywhere.

Comment: A number of comments deleted. Be kind, folks.